# Are these for loops different?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Here is the code

example 1

```
for (var k = 0, l = value.length; k < l; k++, index++) {
    // ...
}
```

example 2

```
var l = value.length;
for (var k = 0; k < l; k++, index++) {
    // ...
}
```

In example 1, variable l is defined inside of the 'for' brackets, so does it mean l is being defined every time the loop goes through? If so then example 2 would be more efficient right?

Comment: *"In example 1, variable l is defined inside of the 'for' brackets, so does it mean l is being defined every time the loop goes through?"*... well, is `k` defined/reset in each iteration?

Comment: why not for (var k = 0; k < value.length; k++, index++) ?

Comment: no it's not, so example 1 and 2 is the same then?

Comment: @BojanKovacevic Because that way you calculate value.length every iteration.

Comment: @BojanKovacevic, in that case it would check value.length everytime (since it is in the conditional)

Comment: They're both the same, except that in example 2 you assign a value to l first, then to k.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are equal in speed. Nothing different.

But I recommand you to use example 2 because it is better to read.

Answer (score 2):

there is no efficiency difference in the snippets.

in the first snipet l = value.length is called once. just like k = 0

Answer (score 0):

Both of them are exactly the same, there is no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Same code, use second one for readability

Answer (score -1):

I am surprised by the answers given here.

Example 1 is a well-known anti-pattern mentioned in many books and articles. It re-calculates l in every loop. Depending on how expensive this (or whatever other unnecessary) operation you put inside the for-call (except the 1st argument), the code may take much longer to execute.

Example 2 is better because the value of `l` is calculated only once and is cached. Caching is a very important concept and this simple examples demonstrates it. Also it will work even if you change `value` inside the loop, whereas the first Example could lead to unexpected results.

In my opinion, the only possible reason to use Example 1 is when you *indeed need* to recalculate `l` for every loop, e.g. when the loop changes `value` and you really want to update `l`.